# Creating a basic single JavaScript function to change different localStorage objects

Tags: javascript, variables, local-storage

I have a beginner question regarding the use of variables in javascript. I'm not new to programing, but I am new to javascript and a few things seem to alude me. My question deals with the following javascript snippet:

```
function use(xue) {
  if(xue=='zero') {
    alert(localStorage.xue)
    if(Number(localStorage.xue) <= 0) {
      alert("Out of that level spell!");
      return false;
    }
    localStorage.zero = Number(localStorage.zero)-1;
    updateGUI();
  }
}
```

Sorry for using an outside site but I couldn't figure out how to format it properly. Anyways it only 13 lines long sooo I hope it isn't a problem.

The issue at hand is that I am storing info in localStorage under localStorage.zero. What I want to do is take the string that is being passed in to be used to update the localStorage data. This way I can just pass in different strings and have this single function update the info for everything.

Right now it just gives me an error saying localStorage.xue, as expected, is undefined.

To clarify if I pass in pizza localStorage.pizza would be modified, or if I pass in hop localStorage.hop would be modified.

Sorry if I am rambling but I am a tad nervous.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the definition for localStorage [here](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#the-localstorage-attribute) (it's w3 draft for Web Storage, so implementations may vary between browser) and Mozilla's guide [here](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/06/localstorage/).

You can probably do something like this to implement the behavior you want:

```
function use(xue) {
    localStorage.setItem(xue, xue);

    if(Number(localStorage[xue]) <= 0) {
        alert("Out of that item!");
        return false;
    } else {
        //You might want to put some more logic here:
        //maybe a check with default value for localStorage.zero like
        //if(localStorage["zero"] !== undefined && localStorage["zero"] !== null)...

        localStorage.zero = Number(localStorage.zero)-1;
        updateGui();
    }
};
```

I think where your function currently is getting hung up is that `localStorage.xue` is equivalent to `localStorage['xue']`, but your intention may be to have `localStorage.xue` refer to whatever you pass in, like `localStorage['pizza']`

In my function above, I try to capture this intent by stating `localStorage[xue]`. Note that the quotes are left off, so it will use the value of xue as the key.

This [link](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/associative.html) on Quirksmode might also help, it explains how Objects in JS can be viewed as associative arrays.

Hope this helps!